# Postgres low performance on 13th gen i9

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, intel, pgbench

I use pgbench for Postgres 12 (default config) and the results are as follows:

`pgbench -i -U postgres -s 50 db_test`

`pgbench -c 1 -j 1 -t 3000 -U postgres db_test`

- number of client: 1
- number of thread: 1
- number of transactions per client: 3000

Result

| Device | CPU | OS | Memory | Kernel | latency average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #1 | Core i5 gen 12th | Ubuntu 20.x | 16GB | 5.x | 0.450 ms |
| #2 | Core i7 gen 10th | Ubuntu 20.x | 16GB | 5.x | 0.625 ms |
| #3 | Core i9 gen 13th ( P-core and E-core enable All) | Ubuntu 20.x | 64GB | 5.x | **10.213 ms** |
| #4 | Core i9 gen 12th ( P-core and E-core enable All) | Ubuntu 20.x | 64GB | 6.7.2 | **12.161ms** |

I have researched but don't have an answer. Please help me

| Device | CPU | OS | Memory | Kernel | Postgresql | latency average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #3 | Core i9 gen 13th ( P-core and E-core enable All) | Ubuntu 22.04.3 | 64GB | 6.5.0-15-generic | 16.1 | **4.836 ms** |
| #3 | Core i9 gen 13th ( P-core and E-core enable All) | Ubuntu 22.04.3 | 64GB | 6.5.0-15-generic | 11.22 | **5.257 ms** |

Comment: are they using the same disk drive?

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes, I use the same SSD for it (All in one /sda), Disk I/O up to 3.0 GB/s when run `sync; dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=1024; sync` . But those are 4 different PC

Comment: at least we can be sure it wasn't the disk. i do curious if other people also have the same problems.

Comment: You'll have to dig deeper. There is nothing anyone can determine based on these scant data.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes, I tried to find out but it doesn't seem very feasible. Although I tried configuring workers (including parallel workers), the results still did not improve. I also tested on gen 12th i9, the result is the same, the performance is not as expected.

Comment: What does `pg_stat_statements` say? Anything interesting from `vmstat`? And so on.

Comment: It could have simply been fixed in a later version. Try Ubuntu 22 and/or [the Postgres 16 package directly from Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)?

Comment: The E cores aren't anywhere near 20x slower, but have you tried disabling E-cores just to see if it makes *any* difference?

Comment: @Schwern I just installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 and Postgres 16, latency is 4.8ms which seems a bit faster

Comment: @PeterCordes I disabled E core in BIOS, it didn't change anything

Comment: I'm skeptical that -t 3000 is large enough to give robust results.  I would go for at least ten minutes of the computers time (`-T 600`) before spending my own time digging into things.

Comment: Is one client and one thread a realistic benchmark? I'd be curious to see what 10 or 100 clients and 2-4 threads do. Also, what's the TPS?